# Есть возможность в C# заглянуть на свой роутер?

Tags: c#, ip, роутер

Можно ли с помощью C# зайти на свой роутер и снять оттуда IP адреса (локальной сети провайдера и внешний адрес сети)?? Если есть такая возможность, то как? /пример кода/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следующий код работает для моего модема. Я снифферил через Opera Dragonfly.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = new WebProxy();
textBox1.Text = client.UploadString("http://192.168.1.1/index.cgi", "v2=y&rs_type=html&A1=admin&A2=admin&auth=auth");//POST запрос. Свои запросы сниффайте.
```

Comment: А Вы не могли бы прокомментировать, как составлять свой запрос ? Буду крайне признателен.

Comment: Я делаю в опере так:
Захожу на модем, Ctrl+Shift+I, вкладка сеть. Ввожу данные и нажимаю "ок". В Dragonfly высвечиваются запросы, находим запрос авторизации и по его примеру составляем свой.

Answer (score 4):

Должна быть возможность получить информацию по [SSH](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH), так же можно написать обычный HTML-парсер. Это далеко не все варианты. Вот ссылки, теория для парсера на С#:

- [Attention to get the latest Official Html Agility Pack releases please use the Nuget Package](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
- [XPath (XML Path Language)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)